# What's the Maximum Villager CareerLevel for each Career?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A Villager generates new trades depending on its `Career` and `CareerLevel` tags, [according to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Data_values):

> - **Career**: The ID of this villager's career. This also influences trading options and the villager's name in the GUI (if it does not
>   have a CustomName). If 0, the next time offers are refreshed, the game
>   will assign a new Career and reset CareerLevel to 1.
> - **CareerLevel**: The current level of this villager's trading options. Influences the trading options generated by the villager; if
>   it is greater than their career's maximum level, no new offers are
>   generated. Increments when a trade causes offers to be refreshed. If
>   0, the next trade to do this will assign a new Career and set
>   CareerLevel to 1. Set to a high enough level and there will be no new
>   trades to release (Career must be set to 1 or above).

What is the the maximum `CareerLevel` value for each corresponding `Career` value?

Comment: While I can't currently answer for each specific profession and career combo, I will say that you do not have to satisfy an exact maximum level to prevent trades from generating. As long as `Career` is not 0 (a value of 1 works for all `Profession`s) and `CareerLevel` is at the max *or higher* for that career (a value of 100 would work for everything, for example), then trades will not generate. e.g. `Career:1,CareerLevel:100` would stop trades for all professions.

Comment: @Skylinerw thanks, yeah I know. But for this software I'm coding I need to detect if that max level has already been reached.

Comment: Thx for the edit @SevenSidedDie. Looks much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer online, so I decided to try them all out myself.

Here are the max CareerLevels for each Career type:

```
Farmer      4
Fisherman   2
Shepherd    2
Fletcher    2
Librarian   6
Cartographer ? (Tested on console)
Cleric      4
Armorer     4
Weapon      3
Tool        3
Butcher     2
Leather     3
Nitwit       ? (Tested on console)
```

Once `CareerLevel` is >= these values, new trades stop generating.